# Multiple count down timers in RecyclerView flickering when scrolled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, countdowntimer

I have implemented count down timer for each item of RecyclerView which is in a fragment activity. The count down timer shows the time remaining for expiry. The count down timer is working fine but when scrolled up it starts flickering. Searched a lot but did not got the good reference. Can any one help me?

This is my RecyclerView adapter

```
public class MyOfferAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyOfferAdapter.FeedViewHolder>{
private final Context mContext;
private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private ArrayList<Transactions> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private String imageURL;
private View mView;
private String mUserEmail;

public MyOfferAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    VolleySingleton mVolley = VolleySingleton.getInstance(mContext);
    mImageLoader = mVolley.getImageLoader();
}


public void addItems(ArrayList<Transactions> items,String userEmail) {
    int count = mItems.size();
    mItems.addAll(items);
    mUserEmail = userEmail;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(count, items.size());
}


@Override
public FeedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    mView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_feed_item_layout, parent, false);
    return new FeedViewHolder(mView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FeedViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.desc.setText(mItems.get(position).getDescription());//replace by title
    holder.scratchDes.setText(mItems.get(position).getScratchDescription());

    long timer = mItems.get(position).getTimerExpiryTimeStamp();
    Date today = new Date();
    final long currentTime = today.getTime();
    long expiryTime = timer - currentTime;


    new CountDownTimer(expiryTime, 500) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
            long minutes = seconds / 60;
            long hours = minutes / 60;
            long days = hours / 24;
            String time = days+" "+"days" +" :" +hours % 24 + ":" + minutes % 60 + ":" + seconds % 60;
            holder.timerValueTimeStamp.setText(time);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            holder.timerValueTimeStamp.setText("Time up!");
        }
    }.start();

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

public static class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView desc;
    TextView scratchDes;
    TextView timerValueTimeStamp;
    ImageView feedImage;
    CardView mCv;

    public FeedViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mCv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_fil);
        desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc_tv_fil);
        feedImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.feed_iv_fil);
        scratchDes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_scratch_description);
        timerValueTimeStamp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_timer_value_time_stamp);

    }

}
```

And this is my xml file used in adapter

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cv_fil"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:elevation="6dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/feed_iv_fil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:tint="@color/grey_tint_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_scratch_description"
            style="@style/ListItemText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="casul shoes"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:padding="10dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_timer_value_time_stamp"
            style="@style/CardTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc_tv_fil"
            style="@style/VendorNameText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/feed_iv_fil"
            android:textColor="#3f3e3f"
            android:padding="10dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And this is screen shot of my RecyclerView
[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This problem is simple.

`RecyclerView` reuses the holders, calling bind each time to update the data in them.

Since you create a `CountDownTimer` each time any data is bound, you will end up with multiple timers updating the same `ViewHolder`.

The best thing here would be to move the `CountDownTimer` in the `FeedViewHolder` as a reference, cancel it before binding the data (if started) and rescheduling to the desired duration.

> ```
> public void onBindViewHolder(final FeedViewHolder holder, final int position) {
>     ...
>     if (holder.timer != null) {
>         holder.timer.cancel();
>     }
>     holder.timer = new CountDownTimer(expiryTime, 500) {
>         ...
>     }.start();
> }
>
> public static class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
>     ...
>     CountDownTimer timer;
>
>     public FeedViewHolder(View itemView) {
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```

This way you will cancel any current timer instance for that `ViewHolder` prior to starting another timer.

Comment: @Lupsaa  I noticed that other solutions use a Handler and Runnable methods and objects to update a new thread off the main thread.  I wonder if those solutions would be better for large numbers of items in a RecyclerView list compared to your solution.  Can you comment?   See the answer by Gergely Kőrössy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166375/set-counter-inside-recyclerview and the answer by H Raval:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860780/recyclerview-with-multiple-countdown-timers-causes-flickering.

Comment: @AJW Since the holders are being recycled, the large number of items in a list does not matter. You can have a list of 10.000 items, if only 10 are visible at a time, you will have maybe ~15 holder instances that are being reused. Here I was just providing an answer to this problem by explaining why he was encountering the flickering. I am sure there are multiple approaches but using Thread / Handler is overkill in my opinion. This solution will not update the holders at the same time since each timer is started when the view is bound.

Comment: @Lupsaa  Ahh, so since the Viewholder does the recycling there are only the 15 holder instances during scrolling at any one time, so that should not overwhelm the main thread?  And as a holder drops out of the View then the timer(s) for that View are cancelled so the main thread will only ever have a relatively small number of timers to handle?

Comment: @AJW That is correct. This is why you have to cancel the previous instance of the view holder timer (if present) and start a new one.

Comment: @Lupsaa Very good, I appreciate you checking back with a reply, cheers.

Comment: use save my day. Thx!

Comment: Can anyone help me,  I am stuck in a similar type of problem but little different. I am showing items Vertically with match_parent height and scrolling is stopped manually. onFinish() method of counter I am to switch to next position (using scrollToPostion(getAdapterPosition)) with reset timer. I really need help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am trying to create a similar timer in kotlin but the holder.timer object throws an object not initialised exception due to which i am not able to cancel the previously created timers. Any help would be appreiciated

Comment: saved my day Thanks

Comment: scrolling time still we have the issue it was restarted

Comment: When i use holder.timer.cancel in onBindViewHolder() just one item work with timer and other work when i scroll on them!!!!

Answer (score 6):

As Andrei Lupsa said you should hold CountDownTimer reference in your ViewHolder, if you didn't want to timer reset when scrolling (onBindViewHolder) , you should check if CountDownTimer reference is null or not in onBindViewHolder :

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final FeedViewHolder holder, final int position) {

      ...

      if (holder.timer == null) {
          holder.timer = new CountDownTimer(expiryTime, 500) {

          ...

          }.start();   
      }
}


public static class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       ...

       CountDownTimer timer;

       public FeedViewHolder(View itemView) {

          .... 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of solution I can think of and they are without using `CountDownTimer` class

1. Make Handler with `postDelayed` method and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in that. In your adapter make calculation for timing. like below code.

in Constructor of adapter class

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
}, 1000);
```

and in you `onBindViewHolder` method

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final FeedViewHolder holder, final int position) {

      updateTimeRemaining(endTime, holder.yourTextView);
}

private void updateTimeRemaining(long endTime, TextView yourTextView) {

    long timeDiff = endTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (timeDiff > 0) {
        int seconds = (int) (timeDiff / 1000) % 60;
        int minutes = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
        int hours = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

        yourTextView.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}:{1}:{2}", hours, minutes, seconds));
    } else {
        yourTextView.setText("Expired!!");
    }
}
```

2. if you think `notifyDataSetChanged()` every millisecond is wrong then here is second option. Create class with `Runnable` implementation and use in in adapter with `setTag()` and `getTag()` method

   ```
        public class DownTimer implements Runnable {

        private TextView yourTextView;
        private long endTime;
        private DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        private Handler handler = new Handler();

        public DownTimer(long endTime, TextView textView) {
            this.endTime = endTime;
            yourTextView = textView;
            formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        }

        public void setEndTime(long endTime) {
            this.endTime = endTime;
        }

        public void start() {
            if (handler != null)
                handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            if (handler != null)
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (handler == null)
                return;

            if (yourTextView == null && endTime == 0)
                return;

            long timeDiff = endTime - System.currentTimeMillis();

            try {
                Date date = new Date(timeDiff);
                yourTextView.setText(formatter.format(date));

            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
    }
   ```

and use in `onBindViewHolder` like this

```
if (holder.yourTextView.getTag() != null) {
    DownTimer downTimer = (DownTimer) holder.yourTextView.getTag();
    downTimer.cancel();
    downTimer.setEndTime(endTime);
    downTimer.start();
} else {
    DownTimer downTimer = new DownTimer(endTime, holder.yourTextView);
    downTimer.start();
    holder.yourTextView.setTag(downTimer);
}
```