# Multiple countdowntimers in recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, countdowntimer

My `countdownTimers` works fine but my problem is all of them sync with last `countdownTimer`(bank or item in `recyclerview`) for example my time interval in item one is 30sec,in item two is 30sec and in item 3 is 60sec when i run my app item 1 and item 2 will be sync with item 3 ,60sec , i think i have one `countdownTimer` in whole `recyclerview` and not for per item.

**This is my bank list view holder :**

```
private static class BankListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private ImageView mImageViewBankLogo;
        private TextView mBankName;
        private TextView mFirstToken;
        private TextView mSecondToken;
        private Button mButtonAddToken;
        private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayoutFirstTokenRowLayout;
        private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayoutSecondTokenRowLayout;
        private Callback mCallback;
        private ProgressBarView mProgressBarView;
        private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

        BankListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, Callback callback) {

            super(itemView);

            mCallback = callback;

            mImageViewBankLogo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_banklist_logo);
            mProgressBarView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_overlay);
            mBankName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_banklist_bankname);
            mFirstToken = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_banklist_firsttoken);
            mSecondToken = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_banklist_secondtoken);
            mButtonAddToken = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_banklist_addtoken);
            mRelativeLayoutSecondTokenRowLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_banklist_secondtokenrowlayout);
            mRelativeLayoutFirstTokenRowLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_banklist_firsttokenrowlayout);
            mButtonAddToken.setOnClickListener(this);
            mRelativeLayoutSecondTokenRowLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
            mRelativeLayoutFirstTokenRowLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (v.getId() == R.id.relativelayout_banklist_firsttokenrowlayout) {
                BankUtil.copyToClipBoard(mFirstToken.getText().toString(), v.getContext());
                SnackbarUtil.showSnackbarNotify(v, v.getContext().getString(R.string.banklist_copyotp), v.getContext());
            }

            if (v.getId() == R.id.relativelayout_banklist_secondtokenrowlayout) {

                BankUtil.copyToClipBoard(mSecondToken.getText().toString(), v.getContext());
                SnackbarUtil.showSnackbarNotify(v, v.getContext().getString(R.string.banklist_copyotp), v.getContext());
            }

            if (v.getId() == R.id.button_banklist_addtoken) {
                mCallback.navigationToQrScanner(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }
```

**And this is my `onBindViewHolder` :**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

.
.
.
bankListViewHolder.mFirstToken.setText(setSpaceBetweenCharacters(generateOtp(bank, 1)));
            bankListViewHolder.mSecondToken.setText(setSpaceBetweenCharacters(generateOtp(bank, 2)));
            bankListViewHolder.mButtonAddToken.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bankListViewHolder.mImageViewBankLogo.setImageDrawable(BankUtil.getLogo(mRoot.getContext(), mBankList.get(position)));

            int currentSecond = (int) (((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) -
                    (bank.getToken().getOtpGenerationPeriodInSeconds() / 1000)) % (bank.getToken().getOtpGenerationPeriodInSeconds() / 1000));

            int diff = ((bank.getToken().getOtpGenerationPeriodInSeconds() / 1000) - currentSecond);


            bankListViewHolder.countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(diff * 1000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    bankListViewHolder.mProgressBarView.setCounter((int) ((bank.getToken().getOtpGenerationPeriodInSeconds() / 1000) -
                            (millisUntilFinished / 1000)) * (360 / (bank.getToken().getOtpGenerationPeriodInSeconds() / 1000)));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    bankListViewHolder.mFirstToken.setText(generateOtp(bank, 1));
                    bankListViewHolder.mSecondToken.setText(generateOtp(bank, 2));
                    mCallback.updateList();
                    start();

                }
            };
            countDownTimerList.add(bankListViewHolder.countDownTimer);
            bankListViewHolder.countDownTimer.start();
            mCallback.saveCountDownTimer(bankListViewHolder.countDownTimer);

.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not put the `countDownTimer` in a `viewHolder`. Keep in mind that a `viewHolder` is a temporary view and it can be reused by other items. This is the characteristic of a `recyclerView` (views can be recycled).

You should put the `countDownTimer` in your List class. One per item. Or create a new ArrayList of `countDownTimers`.

In the `onTick` event you can use `notifyItemChanged` to update their values.

Comment: Thanks but i put countdownTimer in class as a field and in think we should put it in viewholder like  [this] :(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890863/multiple-count-down-timers-in-recyclerview-flickering-when-scrolled)